# how to validate 2 forms on the same page

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to validate 2 forms in same page, please suggest me the best way an also guide me to validate with the form without using save function(this is jst a demo program)

index.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create($temp1);
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->button('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();

echo $this->Form->create($temp2);
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->button('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
               $temp1 = $this->Contact->newEntity($this->request->data);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $temp1 = $this->Contact->patchEntity($temp1, $this->request->data);
            if($this->Contact->save($temp1))
              {  
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are you submitting form on same action.

Comment: NO, it jst that two different form in same page. i jst know to use above controller code to validate 1 form but dont know, weather i have to create one more function for another form or in same function.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily validate your forms by using [jQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/). Check out the link.

Comment: Sorry for the link mistake.

Comment: no prob but how i m going to save my data of 2 forms, i want to know which is the correct method for my program

Comment: I am unclear about your form saving method and your form. Do you need to save the data in the same table or in different tables?

Comment: different table thats the main concern because in model i can define only one table

Answer (score 0):

For validation, go to Model/Table/PostTable.php

```
  public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('name');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('email');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('password');

    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can validate through two form with different different id in jquery validation